# Run WIX installer package in a non-User mode and Provide answer file to a WIX installation package

Tags: wix, wix3.7, wix3.8

it is possible to install wix installer in non user mode and it take the input from the  answer file this is the screen

[image]

answer file will put the Server name and data base name.

```
<serverName>localhost\SqlExpress</serverName><databaseName></databaseName>
```

This is the my answer file

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer does not have a facility for answer files. Instead, automated behavior is provided through property settings.

The primary way to set properties for an installer operation is via the msiexec command-line. You would probably want to use one of the quiet/unattended modes, too.

Another way, since an MSI file is a database, is to set properties in a copy of the MSI.